# Get variable from 4th line in a while read loop bash

Tags: linux, bash, text, while-loop

Got a txt file with this scheme: (just 8 of 10k lines)

```
Paris: 405
Paris_average: 20
Paris_lenght: 30
score: 5.4
London: 605
London_average: 30
London_lenght: 30
score: 6.3
```

What i need to do is to get the "score" a variable , which is always at the 4th line, and where its value is bigger than "6.0", the 3 lines above needs to be conserved.

So, giving the sample as input, when the script will run, here's the output:

```
London: 605
London_average: 30
London_lenght: 30
score: 6.3
```

I've thought about a "while..read" loop for the 4 lines, but I don't know how to go forward. 
Tagged bash, but also perl solutions are appreciated.

Comment: I would personnally recommend to use **awk**. What have you coded up to now?

Comment: just a while read for $line1 $line2 $line3 $line4.   How do you think you can implement an awk command to preserve the 3 lines above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '$1=="score:" && $2 > 6{ print r1 r2 r3 $0 }{ r1=r2; r2=r3; r3=$0 ORS }' file
```

- `$1=="score:" && $2 > 6` - check main conditions; `$1` and `$2` are the 1st and 2nd fields respectively
- `r1=r2; r2=r3; r3=$0 ORS` - consecutively *reassign* each of 3 consequent records into variables `r3` -> `r2` -> `r1`
- `print r1 r2 r3 $0` - print a relevant *score* line along with previous 3 records

---

Sample output:

```
London: 605
London_average: 30
London_lenght: 30
score: 6.3
```

---

Bonus **`grep`** solution:

```
grep -B3 '^score: [6-9]' file
```

---

In case if pattern `score:` line goes as 2nd line withing 4-lined section/block:

```
grep -B1 -A2 '^score: [6-9]' file
```

Comment: just wondering.. what if the "score:" was on the 2nd line? I'm trying to modify the script provided by you, but can't figure out how to reassign properly records to variables.    I've tried    ..{ print r1 $0 r3 r4 }{ r1=$0 ; $0=r3 ; r3=r4 ORS }' .. but it prints only the first two lines after "score.." so it doesn't seem to recognize other variables.

Comment: @Shred, you may initiate a new question to deal with new conditions

Comment: Imho isn't useful. Just asking a way to handle the variable into the second line, using your method.

Comment: @Shred, I should observe a new input data. How can I know how you are swapping the remaining lines?

Comment: Copied input on pastebin.com, due to limited characters of comments. https://pastebin.com/SB6pNZ6K

Comment: @Shred, I see the input, now show the expected output in same way

Comment: Desidered output when "score" value is bigger than 6: https://pastebin.com/RJ7Vt39L

Comment: @Shred, enjoy my additional approaches

Comment: Grep solutions is poor, cuz it doesn't filter value bigger than 100.

Comment: @Shred, "filter value bigger than 100" - that's another story, another condition which is out the current question. Dragging out with indirect conditions is bad behavior

Comment: Every number with two or more figures are bigger than 6.  "100" is just an example. This grep solution filters in a tricky way, only when numbers start from 6 to 9.

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$0;} /score:/ && $2>6 && FNR!=1{print a[FNR-3] RS a[FNR-2] RS a[FNR-1] RS $0}'   Input_file
```

Adding non one liner form of same too now:

```
awk '
{
  a[FNR]=$0
}
/score:/ && $2>6 && FNR!=1{
  print a[FNR-3] RS a[FNR-2] RS a[FNR-1] RS $0
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
{
  a[FNR]=$0                                    ##Creating an array named a whose index is FNR(current line) and value is assigned as current line to it.
}
/score:/ && $2>6 && FNR!=1{                    ##Checking condition here where checking if a line is having string score: in it and 2nd field is greater than 6 and line number is NOT one then do following:
  print a[FNR-3] RS a[FNR-2] RS a[FNR-1] RS $0 ##Printing the value of a[FNR-3](3rd line from current line), RS(record seprator) a[FNR-2](2nd line from current line) a[FNR-1](prevoius line of current line)
}
'   Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here too.
```

Comment: Good answer too. Could you please explain in two lines what actually "FNR" does here? I've read is used to do comparisons between two group of file, lines..

Comment: @Shred, will add explanation too now.

Comment: I must note that this approach will map the whole file into memory (putting every record into array)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 your example script prints lines before the one where the condition is verified. What if I want to print the lines after? I've tried using   {print a[FNR++1] RS a[FNR++2]}   but, for some reasons, when using plus instead of minus it prints only blank lines.

Comment: @Shred, try using `FNR+1` and `FNR+2` please don't use `++` there, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 same. Only blank lines.

Comment: @Shred, aahhh I got it, since no assignment for that array elements how come they will come then :) You need to tell your conditions so that I could give you a solution then on same.

Comment: Thanks. Input: https://pastebin.com/SB6pNZ6K           Desidered output: https://pastebin.com/RJ7Vt39L

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk and expecting the score to be of form `[0.9].[0-9]` and less than 10.0:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\nscore: ...\n"}RT~/[6789]\./{printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' file
London: 605
London_average: 30
London_lenght: 30
score: 6.3
```

Explained:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    RS="\nscore: ...\n"   # record separator is the score line
}
RT~/[6789]\./ {           # if the score starts with a digit 6-9
    printf "%s%s",$0,RT   # output the record
}' file
```

---

Another for reqular awk(s) using buffering and printing:

```
$ awk '{b=b $0 (NR%4?ORS:"")}!(NR%4){if($2>6)print b;b=""}'  file
London: 605
London_average: 30
London_lenght: 30
score: 6.3
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
{
    b=b $0 (NR%4?ORS:"")  # buffer records
}
!(NR%4) {                 # on every 4th record
    if($2>6)              # if condition met
        print b           # print buffer
    b=""                  # reset buffer
}'  file
```

Comment: What if the score is 21 ? or -7 ? Those might be edge cases, but we dont know for sure the scores are always in the `[0-10[` range

Comment: @Aserre Modify the regex accordingly. That's why I clearly stated the expectations for the score.

Comment: First one isn't good because if value is 120, for example, doesn't match the condition.

Comment: @Shred It's good as soon as I know the reqs for the score, like mentioned in the answer and in the comments. But it is more of a test for myself to see how to use `RT` and regex. (Quoting Marty McFly: _I guess you guys aren't ready for that yet. But your kids are gonna love it!_)

Comment: @JamesBrown you're awk solution works. I've tried to run it against a file composed by long lines (every 3rd line is around 10k chars) and, don't know why, it skips these lines sometimes. Is there any kind of known problems against huge txt file?

Comment: @Shred None that comes to my mind atm. Could there be some interfereing charactes in those lines, like `\r`?